# First time Git user. Using railstutorial.org on cloud9 and made a mistake setting up a BitBucket repository

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, railstutorial.org

Just starting railstutorial.org, using cloud9 IDE and setting up a Bitbucket repository. I've got my public key set, but when creating my first repository, I mistakenly named it my username. I want to keep it in line with the tutorial where the repository shares the name of the app "hello_app. I went through the "I have an existing project" setup for the first/"wrong" repository, now when I try to set up my project with a newly created repository, these instructions give me an error.

Instructions on BitBucket.org:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:cbyhlm/hello_app.git

git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time

git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

Errors:

```
:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:cbyhlm/hello_app.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $ git push -u origin --all
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I don't know enough about Git to get my new correctly named repository set up in cloud9. I tried deleting the repository, and then even deleted and recreated a bitbucket account. So to me that means it something in my actual app directory that has been set that isn't allowing me to set up a new repository using the only instructions I'm familiar with at this point. Can anyone help me do that?

For reference, here is the tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

When you added your first remote it was named `origin`. You cannot add another remote with the same name. You need to remove the remote you added and then follow the steps again. You can remove the remote you added like this:

```
git remote remove <name>
```

In this case substitute `<name>` with `origin`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get this error when I try that